# selectpicker not working when datatable is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am including the following css styling and scripts in my MVC ASP.net application. The select picker dropdown does not work when I include the following `datatables` `css` and `.js` file

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

The following snippet shows the order of inclusion of all the `css` and `.js` files in the MVC `asp.net` application in the `_Layout.cshtml`

```
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrapcss")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/jqc-1.11.3,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

I did go through other solutions on stackoverflow. However it did not fix the issue.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Check the console for any errors, and include that in the question's body.

Comment: If i add 
{
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
}

Before select-picker, I dont get any errors but still the drop-down doesnt work. If I add it after the select-picker, i get $(...).selectpicker is not a function error.